# Using carouFredSel, but am unable to figure out how to add a text overlay to each image

Tags: html

Here is my code that I am working with

```
<div class="property-featured clearfix">
<div class="images">
<div class="caroufredsel-wrap">
<ul>
<li><img src="images/property/property-details1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
<li><img src="images/property/property-details2.jpg" alt=""/></li>
<li><img src="images/property/property-details3.jpg" alt=""/></li>
<li><img src="images/property/property-details4.jpg" alt=""/></li>
<li><img src="images/property/property-details5.jpg" alt=""/></li>
<li><img src="images/property/property-details6.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="thumbnails">
<div class="thumbnails-wrap">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details1-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details2-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details3-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details4-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details5-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details6-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details1-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details2-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details3-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details4-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details5-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/property/property-details6-thumbs.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<a class="caroufredsel-prev" href="#"></a>
<a class="caroufredsel-next" href="#"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

My issue is that I need text or an image to overlay each of the larger, full size images. I've tried to set a div for text before each list item closes, but that simply places the text underneath the full size image and above the thumbnails.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a link to working code?

Comment: Here- http://html.nootheme.com/citilights/property-details.html